# Schema Validation failure for Bulk insert using MongooseJs on NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Trying to achieve CSV import so I'm using the bulk insert in NodeJs using MonggoseJs and sharing here piece of script.

**Description:**

If I insert a data using 'model.save' validation is working properly for min length of a string and email unique, below the Schema and Script for bulk insert.

```
// User Schema.
{
    "title": {type: String, enum:["Mr", "Ms", "Mrs","Miss","Mstr"]},
    "firstName": {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,         
        minlength: 2
    },
    "lastName":  {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    },
    "gender": {type: String, enum: ["Male","Female","Other"]},
    "email" : {type: String, unique: true, required: true, trim: true}
}
```

Script: Promise which will perform for bulk insert

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var bulk = User.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

    let _oUserOne =new User({
        "title": Mr,
        "firstName" : "A",
        "lastName" : "S",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "email" : "xxx@domain.com"
    })

    let _oUserTwo =new User({
        "title": Mr,
        "firstName" : "A",
        "lastName" : "S",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "email" : "xxx@domain.com" // Duplicate entry of email
    })

    bulk.insert(_oUserOne);
    bulk.insert(_oUserTwo);

    bulk.execute(function (err, r) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error in bulk insert\n", err);
            resolve({ result: r, error: err });
        }
        console.log("OK: Inserted successfully!");
        resolve({ result: r, error: null });
    });
});
```

Comment: `User.collection.` You are accessing the `Collection` object from the core driver. There is **no validation** in the core driver. Mongoose has a `bulkWrite()` on the model anyway, but again we don't do validation here at all. Bulk things are meant to be "fast", so you don't pass them through validators. Fix the source to be valid "first" is the approach instead. This is "by design".

Comment: Ok, Thank you! I got the problem and I'm using now model.save only.